# query to combine two tables

Tags: json, sql-server

Is there a specific way to combine database table columns and get data in json format

Comment: What is your SQL Server version?

Comment: @Zhorov Latest version ie.,15

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the information for this JSON output can be retrieved using only the data in second table. Do you really need the information from the first table?

Comment: @Zhorov yes. We need data from first table too. I’m trying to combine data from two tables

Answer (score 0):

You  first need Join two table:
Then Create JSON string.
Sample:

```
With t
as(
Select *
From table1 inner join table2 ON st_code=vSt
)
Select * from t
FOR JSON PATH
```

you can use concatt function  , sting_agg(ColumnName,',') function and etc for create any different columns.